# bash script to iterate directories and create tar files

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, directory, ubuntu-14.04

I was searching for ways to create a bash file that would iterate all the folders in a directory, and create a tar.gz file for each of those directories.
(This is used specifically for ubuntu/drupal website - but could be useful in other scenarios.)

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Please show your code. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After lots of searching, combining scripts and testing, I found the following works very well when run from within the main directory.
This might be slightly different depending on version of bash, what version of ubuntu and from where you schedule or run the bash file. (Run by typing sh createDirectoryTarFiles.sh at command line from within the parent folder.)
The echo line is not necessary - just for viewing purposes.

```
   for D in *; do
      if [ -d "${D}" ]; then
         tx="${D%????}"
         echo "Directory is ${D} - and name of file would be $tx"
         tar -zcvf "$tx.tar.gz" "${D}"
      fi
   done
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `find` to search for directories between mindepth and maxdepth and then create the tars

```
find .  -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -exec tar czf $(basename {}).tar.gz {} \;
```